# Oracle stored procedure not returning all results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on creating a new Oracle package for part of a web site.  When I run the package I get six results and when I run the SQL directly I get eight results.  I have everything hard coded right now so there is nothing dynamic about the SQL.  Since I am using the exact hard coded SQL I don’t understand how they could be different results.

```
PACKAGE RESULTS:
    BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (1000000);
    INTERNET.Appt.GetAppointments(:p_OpenAppointments);
    END;
```

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE INTERNET."Appt" 
AS
    type ResultSet is ref cursor;

```
procedure GetAppointments(
    p_Appointments OUT ResultSet );
```

END Appt;
/

```
procedure GetAppointments(
        p_Appointments OUT ResultSet )
    IS
        v_sql varchar2(5000);
    BEGIN

OPEN p_Appointments FOR
SELECT 
    tableC.legalname Carrier, 
    tableAli.st State, 
    tableType.contracttypename ContractType, 
    tableStatus.contractsttsname Status,
    tableContracting.carrieragtnbr ApptNo, 
    NVL (TO_CHAR (tableAppt.apptdt, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'N/A') Effective, 
    tableAppt.apptdt,
    tableAppt.dtverified,
    tableAli.residentyn,
    decode(nvl(tableAli.residentyn, 'U'), 'R', 'Resident', 'N', 'Non-Resident', 'Unknown') residentdesc
FROM 
    tableType,
    tableC, 
    tableContract, 
    tableSubAccount, 
    tableContracting, 
    tableStatus, 
    tableAli, 
    tableAppt, 
    organization 
WHERE 
    tableAppt.contractingid = tableContracting.contractingid 
    AND tableAppt.agtlicenseid = tableAli.agtlicenseid 
    AND tableContracting.gasubaccountid = tableSubAccount.gasubaccountid 
    AND tableContracting.agentnbrid = tableAli.agentnbrid 
    AND tableContracting.contracttypeid = tableType.contracttypeid 
    AND tableAppt.currentstatus = tableStatus.contractsttsid 
    AND tableSubAccount.gacontractid = tableContract.gacontractid 
    AND tableContract.carrierid = tableC.carrierid 
    AND tableSubAccount.organizationid = organization.organizationid
    AND tableContracting.agentnbrid = 123456
    AND 
    (
        (tableAppt.currentstatus = 1)
        OR        
        (tableAppt.currentstatus = 3 AND tableAppt.dateterminated >= trunc(sysdate-60))
    )
ORDER BY 
    tableStatus.contractsttsname,
    tableC.legalname;


END GetAppointments

SQL RESULTS:

SELECT 
    tableC.legalname Carrier, 
    tableAli.st State, 
    tableType.contracttypename ContractType, 
    tableStatus.contractsttsname Status,
    tableContracting.carrieragtnbr ApptNo, 
    NVL (TO_CHAR (tableAppt.apptdt, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'N/A') Effective, 
    tableAppt.apptdt,
    tableAppt.dtverified,
    tableAli.residentyn,
    decode(nvl(tableAli.residentyn, 'U'), 'R', 'Resident', 'N', 'Non-Resident', 'Unknown') residentdesc
FROM 
    tableType,
    tableC, 
    tableContract, 
    tableSubAccount, 
    tableContracting, 
    tableStatus, 
    tableAli, 
    tableAppt, 
    organization 
WHERE 
    tableAppt.contractingid = tableContracting.contractingid 
    AND tableAppt.agtlicenseid = tableAli.agtlicenseid 
    AND tableContracting.gasubaccountid = tableSubAccount.gasubaccountid 
    AND tableContracting.agentnbrid = tableAli.agentnbrid 
    AND tableContracting.contracttypeid = tableType.contracttypeid 
    AND tableAppt.currentstatus = tableStatus.contractsttsid 
    AND tableSubAccount.gacontractid = tableContract.gacontractid 
    AND tableContract.carrierid = tableC.carrierid 
    AND tableSubAccount.organizationid = organization.organizationid
    AND tableContracting.agentnbrid = 123456
    AND 
    (
        (tableAppt.currentstatus = 1)
        OR        
        (tableAppt.currentstatus = 3 AND tableAppt.dateterminated >= trunc(sysdate-60))
    )
ORDER BY 
    tableStatus.contractsttsname,
    tableC.legalname;
```

Comment: I assume `resultset` is declared somewhere as a `sys_refcursor`?

Comment: Yes it is.  type ResultSet is ref cursor;  I updated the original question with this information as well.

Comment: Are you running both in the same environment? Are there uncommitted transactions?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but defining a PL/SQL package name in double quotes (`"Appt"`) is just asking for problems down the road.

Comment: They are running in the same environment which is a test database.  They are all committed transactions.  The records were entered into the database about five years ago.